# Using "if let" with logical "or" operator

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm trying to write the following block of code in a single `if let` line:

```
 if let amount = datasource?.incrementForCount?(count) {

        count += amount
    }

    else if let amount = datasource?.fixedIncrement {
        count += amount
    }
```

when I try something like:

```
 if let amount = datasource?.incrementForCount?(count) ||  let amount = datasource?.fixedIncrement {

        count += amount
    }
```

I got a compile time error.

I don't think that `where` clause is possible for this case.

Is it possible to combine the two `if let` statements into a single `ORed` one?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try to use `??` operator:

```
if let amount = datasource?.incrementForCount?(count) ?? datasource?.fixedIncrement 
{
    count += amount
}
```

> is it possible to combine the 2 if let statements into a single ORed one ?

It is possible to have several `let` statements like

```
if let a = optionalA, b = optionalB { ... }
```

And all of them should return non-nil value to pass.

But if you also want to use a logical condition it:

1. Could be only the one
2. Should be placed on the first place, before any let statements

Comment: is there a cleaner solution to use when there are further ORed conditions instead of nesting ?? operator statetments ?

Comment: @JAHelia No. You can have only one logical condition in if statement (not `where`) and it should be placed on the first place, before any `let` statements.

Comment: I don't know when it was changed but Swift 5.4 requires the following syntax: `if let a = optionalA, let b = optionalB { ... }`

Answer (score 19):

No, you can't OR two `if-let` statements, or even an `if-let` statement with a non if-let condition, because that would completely defeat the purpose of the `if-let` statement. `if-let` ensures that you can only enter the body of the statement if the optional could be successfully unwrapped into the variable.

```
let str:String? = nil
if let s = str || true {
  //s is nil, yet you're still in the if-let body
}
```

In the above example you would still enter the optional body even if `s` were nil, in which case you would still have to check whether `s`is nil or not inside the body, rendering the first `if-let` check pointless.

Comment: Disagreed. There are instances where you need to use an optional when a condition is met, but if that condition's not met you don't need to use that optional. Example: you need an ID to initialize a controller, but depending on what the server gives, you might use the default value. This is when it's best to combine `if let` and `||`  since the init code is the same. 
This is convenient:
`if let id = model.id || model.usesDefaultValue { /*init code here once*/ }` 
This is not:
`if let id = model.id { /*init here*/ } else if model.usesDefaultValue { /*same init - code repetition*/ }`

Comment: This is correct -- to clarify, let's say Swift tried to allow that statement. When `if let s = str` evaluates to true, that means that `s` is not an optional, but when evaluates to false, that means `s` would need to be an optional.  `s` cannot both be an optional and a non-optional at the same time, so it can't compile.